# How to create strings using c/c++ macros arguments

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to achieve this:

> char * fname = "results5.txt"

Using a macro like this:

```
#define FILENAME(NUM) "results" NUM ".txt"

int number = 5;
char * fname = FILENAME(number);
```

It's possible to do it that way? What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: If you want `results5.txt` out of that, I'm afraid the **preprocesor** isn't going to rescue you. Regarding what is wrong? Lookup "How a C program is compiled", paying close attention to the *preprocessing* phase. @duDE I think you're going to need a `char filename[PATH_MAX]` and a **`sprintf()`** call for the basic need you're trying to fill.

Comment: Why can't you use a function at runtime?

Comment: If you want to change this sort of information at compile time you can  use -D to pass in a value.
g++ ... -DFILENAME="results5.txt"

char* fname = FILENAME;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C

Since you tagged C and want macro based solution, use a `#` in the macro

```
#define FILENAME(NUM) "results"#NUM".txt"
                               ^^^^^
char *fname = FILENAME(5);
```

Be careful in this way you can not use variables.

```
int number = 5;
char *fname = FILENAME(number); // IMPOSSIBLE
```

Otherwise, to use variables, you should use functions.

---

### C++

made everything easier

```
std::string FileName(int d)
{
    return "results"+ std::to_string(d) +".txt";

    //  or...
    //  std::ostringstream str;
    //  str << "results" << d << ".txt";
    //  return str.str();
}

...

int number = 5;
std::string filename = FileName(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question both `C` and `C++`. For the `C++` part, the easiest would be:

```
inline std::string FILENAME(int number) {
  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "results" << number << ".txt";
  return s.str();
}



int number = 5;
std::string fname = FILENAME(number);
```

Of course, you'd probably use a nicer name than all-uppercase `FILENAME` for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int number = 5;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "results" << number << ".txt"
std::string filename = ss.str(); //if you need it as C++ string
char const* filename = ss.str().c_str(); //if you need it as C string
```